# At what level of x (continuous measure) do two binary measures diverge?

Tags: statistical-significance, binary-data, continuous-data

Participants at different ages (continuous-data) responded to yes/no questions 
(binary-data) in two conditions (within-subjects). Younger participants responded similarly to both questions, whereas older participants did not (i.e., the regression lines diverge as age increases).

How can I determine when (i.e., at what age) the difference first becomes significant, i.e., at what level of x, responses to the two conditions first significantly diverge?